# angular 2 - ng-bootstrap NgbTypeahead: concat multiple sources

Tags: angular, rxjs

I would like to concatenate the results of more http sources in my typeahead results. 
Basically as implemented in plunker https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/app/components/typeahead/demos/http/plnkr.html.
add a second wiki source...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out to **solve** the issue, by nesting correctly the requests.
Substitute code below in plunker.

```
search(term: string) {
if (term === '') {
  return Observable.of([]);
}

let wikiUrl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php';
let wikiUrl2 = 'https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php';
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('search', term);
params.set('action', 'opensearch');
params.set('format', 'json');
params.set('callback', 'JSONP_CALLBACK');

return this._jsonp
  .get(wikiUrl, {search: params)
  .map(response => response.json()[1])
  .switchMap(responseEN => this._jsonp
    .get(wikiUrl2, {search: params)
    .map(response => {
      let responseDE = response.json()[1];
      responseEN.forEach(function(value){
        console.log(value);
        responseDE.push(value);
      })
      return responseDE;
      })
  );
```

}